# Is it possible to add custom field to Product?

Tags: commercetools

I recently work with Commercetools and I have a question.

I've looked on CustomFields documentation https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-custom-fields#custom and it became interesting to me.

How can we add custom field to product level and to variant level? Is it possible? Or can we add CustomFields to ProductType?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the request.

Custom types are not needed on products as the product types define all the attributes required for a product.

see https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-productTypes#attributedefinition for a complete documentation of the attributes you can define.

Best Regards
Brian